# RMI client-server NotBoundException

Tags: java, rmi

I am trying to run the rmi tutorial on oracles' website. I am able to run the server, but I receive an error running the client. The error I receive when try to run the cleint is a no`NotBoundException` exception. How do I fix this error?

Below is the code and exception

Exception

```
Client exception: java.rmi.NotBoundException: Hello
java.rmi.NotBoundException: Hello
        at sun.rmi.registry.RegistryImpl.lookup(RegistryImpl.java:166)
        at sun.rmi.registry.RegistryImpl_Skel.dispatch(Unknown Source)
        at sun.rmi.server.UnicastServerRef.oldDispatch(UnicastServerRef.java:411)
        at sun.rmi.server.UnicastServerRef.dispatch(UnicastServerRef.java:272)
        at sun.rmi.transport.Transport$1.run(Transport.java:200)
        at sun.rmi.transport.Transport$1.run(Transport.java:197)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at sun.rmi.transport.Transport.serviceCall(Transport.java:196)
        at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport.handleMessages(TCPTransport.java:568)
        at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport$ConnectionHandler.run0(TCPTransport.java:826)
        at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport$ConnectionHandler.lambda$run$0(TCPTransport.java:683)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport$ConnectionHandler.run(TCPTransport.java:682)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
        at sun.rmi.transport.StreamRemoteCall.exceptionReceivedFromServer(Unknown Source)
        at sun.rmi.transport.StreamRemoteCall.executeCall(Unknown Source)
        at sun.rmi.server.UnicastRef.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at sun.rmi.registry.RegistryImpl_Stub.lookup(Unknown Source)
        at example.hello.Client.main(Client.java:52)
```

Server

```
package example.hello;

import java.rmi.registry.Registry;
import java.rmi.registry.LocateRegistry;
import java.rmi.RemoteException;
import java.rmi.server.UnicastRemoteObject;

public class Server implements Hello {

    public Server() {}

    public String sayHello() {
        return "Hello, world!";
    }

    public static void main(String args[]) {

        try {
            Server obj = new Server();
            Hello stub = (Hello) UnicastRemoteObject.exportObject(obj, 0);

            // Bind the remote object's stub in the registry
            Registry registry = LocateRegistry.getRegistry();
            registry.bind("Hello", stub);

            System.err.println("Server ready");
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.err.println("Server exception: " + e.toString());
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Client

```
package example.hello;

import java.rmi.registry.LocateRegistry;
import java.rmi.registry.Registry;

public class Client {

    private Client() {}

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        String host = (args.length < 1) ? null : args[0];
        try {
            Registry registry = LocateRegistry.getRegistry(host);
            Hello stub = (Hello) registry.lookup("Hello");
            String response = stub.sayHello();
            System.out.println("response: " + response);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.err.println("Client exception: " + e.toString());
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Interface

```
package example.hello;

import java.rmi.Remote;
import java.rmi.RemoteException;

public interface Hello extends Remote {
    String sayHello() throws RemoteException;
}
```

Comment: Did you run the server before the client?

Comment: Yes and the server works, the client causes the error.

Comment: Are you sure you haven't mistyped `"Hello"` somewhere? Or the hostname?

Comment: Yeah nothing like that

Comment: Hard to believe. This code works. I suggest you paste it back into your project and recompile and re-test.

Answer (score -1):

You need to launch the [RMI] registry. Method `getRegistry()` does not launch the registry. Method `createRegistry(int)` launches the registry. You need to change this line in your class `Server`

```
Registry registry = LocateRegistry.getRegistry();
```

to this

```
Registry registry = LocateRegistry.createRegistry(1099);
```

Note that 1099 is the default port used by RMI.

Comment: He managed to connect to the Registry and get a `NotBoundException` from it. Therefore the Registry *was* running. `createRegistry()` isn't the only way to achieve that.